# CUDA Kernel running repeatedly for each launch

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

I'm having a very odd bug with a CUDA (v5.0) code. Basically, I am trying to use device memory to accumulate values for a program that needs to take the average of a bunch of pixels. In order to do this I have two kernels, one which accumulates a sum in floating point array, sum_mask, and the other which does the division at the end, avg_mask. The odd thing is that both kernel's do exactly the operation I want them to do, multiplied by 14. I suspect it is somehow a synchronization or grid/block dim problem but I have checked and rechecked everything and cannot figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit 1, Problem Statement: Running a CUDA kernel that does any accumulation process gives me what I would expect if each pixel were run consecutively by 14 threads. The specific input that is given me trouble has width=1280, height=720

Edit 2: Deleted some code in the snippets that was seemingly unrelated to the problem.

kernel:

```
__global__ void sum_mask(uint16_t * pic_d, float * mask_d,uint16_t width, uint16_t height)
{
unsigned short col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
unsigned short row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
unsigned short offset = col + row*width;
mask_d[offset] = mask_d[offset] + 1.0f; //This ends up incrementing by 14
//mask_d[offset] = mask_d[offset] + __uint2float_rd(pic_d[offset]); //This would increment by 14*pic_d[offset]
}
```

code to call kernel:

```
uint32_t dark_subtraction_filter::update_mask_collection(uint16_t * pic_in)
{
// Synchronous
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaSetDevice(DSF_DEVICE_NUM));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(pic_in_host,pic_in,width*height*sizeof(uint16_t),cudaMemcpyHostToHost));
averaged_samples++;
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpyAsync(pic_out_host,mask_device,width*height*sizeof(uint16_t),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,dsf_stream));

/* This part is for testing */
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaStreamSynchronize(dsf_stream));
        std::cout << "#samples: " << averaged_samples << std::endl;
        std::cout << "pic_in_host: " << pic_in_host[9300] << "maskval: " << pic_out_host[9300] <<std::endl;

//Asynchronous
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpyAsync(picture_device,pic_in_host,width*height*sizeof(uint16_t),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,dsf_stream));

sum_mask<<< gridDims, blockDims,0,dsf_stream>>>(picture_device, mask_device,width,height);


return averaged_samples;
}
```

constructor:

```
dark_subtraction_filter::dark_subtraction_filter(int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaSetDevice(DSF_DEVICE_NUM));
width=nWidth;
height=nHeight;
blockDims = dim3(20,20,1);
gridDims = dim3(width/20, height/20,1);
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaStreamCreate(&dsf_stream));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaHostAlloc( (void **)&pic_in_host,width*height*sizeof(uint16_t),cudaHostAllocPortable)); //cudaHostAllocPortable??

HANDLE_ERROR(cudaHostAlloc( (void **)&pic_out_host,width*height*sizeof(float),cudaHostAllocPortable)); //cudaHostAllocPortable??

HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc( (void **)&picture_device, width*height*sizeof(uint16_t)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc( (void **)&mask_device, width*height*sizeof(float)));
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaPeekAtLastError());
}
```

Comment: You haveforgotten to tell us what the problem is and to ask a actual question. Please edit your question to explain exactly what is going wrong, along with the simplest complete code which reproduces whatever your issue.

Comment: Please provide values for all constants (e.g. BLOCK_SIDE) and ranges for any input value. A quick guess is that the offset calculation is overflowing offset 14 times which would be about correct if width == height == 1000. Calculations on short will be slower than for short. The same is true for use of uint16_t input parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the help on how to make my question more answerable, I have  replaced BLOCK_SIDE with its value (20) and specified the input size for which I am having a problem. When you say "calculations on short will be slower than for short", do you mean slower than for int?

Comment: By the way @GregSmith, your suggestion about my 'unsigned short offset' overflow was correct. I'd be happy to mark yours as the right answer if you feel like posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable offset is declared as a unsigned short. The offset calculation was overflowing the 16-bit storage class. If width = height = 1000 this would result in approximately 14 overflows resulting in the observed behavior.

The parameter passing and offset calculation are performed on unsigned short/uint16_t. The calculations will likely be quicker if the data types and calculations are of type int.